# Order by date MySQL query ordering by day only, not full date

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I'm trying to sort by most recent date at top, down to oldest result at bottom. This is the query

```
SELECT headline, story, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%M-%Y") AS date, 
name, logo, tpf_parks.park_id, url, alt, description
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id 
LEFT JOIN tpf_images ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_images.news_id 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The results are ordered wrong though, it is sorting it by day only so results are ordered like this: `25-march-2013, 23-april-2013, 19-febuary-2013, 10-may-2013` etc. I think its because the way I am displaying the date `DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%M-%Y") AS date`, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT headline, story, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%M-%Y") AS Displaydate, 
    name, logo, tpf_parks.park_id, url, alt, description
    FROM tpf_news
    INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id 
    LEFT JOIN tpf_images ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_images.news_id 
    ORDER BY date DESC
```

This way,mySQL will order by the true date field, and your application code will show the date formatted the way you want it

Answer (score 3):

Rename your alias, it is ambiguous

```
SELECT headline, story, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%M-%Y") AS formatted_date, 
name, logo, tpf_parks.park_id, url, alt, description
FROM tpf_news
INNER JOIN tpf_parks ON tpf_news.park_id = tpf_parks.park_id 
LEFT JOIN tpf_images ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_images.news_id 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Then the DB engine can use `date` to order and knows the difference to the original column and the formatted one.